# How to resize the images to fit in fixed size div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working on project(social media web app), where user has permission to upload variety of media. I will explain problem with example, let's say I have div of 500px*300px and I am getting images of various dimensions, it could be portrait or landscape or could be small images like 50px*50px. I want to fit such image in fixed size div, without losing its aspect ratio or without getting it cropped or without getting stretched. I tried with css properties but none of them seems to work fine with all type images, I am struggling to find solution for this.

Component to render image:

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function Example(props) {
  const myRef = useRef(null);
  const [dimensionofImg, setDimensionofImg] = React.useState(null);
  const [dimensionsofDiv, setDimensionsofDiv] = React.useState(null);
  const [imagedimensions, setImagedimensions] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setDimensionsofDiv({
      width: myRef.current.offsetWidth,
      height: myRef.current.offsetHeight
    });
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let dimensionTocompare;
    if (
      dimensionofImg &&
      dimensionofImg.width < dimensionofImg &&
      dimensionofImg.height
    ) {
      dimensionTocompare = dimensionsofDiv.width;
      let changedWidth =
        (dimensionTocompare * dimensionofImg.width) / dimensionofImg.height;
      setImagedimensions({
        maxWidth: "",
        maxHeight: "100%",
        width: changedWidth,
        height: ""
      });
    } else if (
      dimensionofImg &&
      dimensionofImg.width > dimensionofImg &&
      dimensionofImg.height
    ) {
      dimensionTocompare = dimensionsofDiv.height;
      let changedHeight =
        (dimensionTocompare * dimensionofImg.height) / dimensionofImg.width;
      setImagedimensions({
        maxWidth: "100%",
        maxHeight: "",
        width: "",
        height: changedHeight
      });
    }
    else if (
      dimensionofImg && dimensionofImg.width == dimensionofImg && dimensionofImg.height
    ) {
      
      setImagedimensions({
        maxWidth: "100%",
        maxHeight: "100%",
        width: "",
        height: ""
      });
    }
  }, [dimensionofImg, dimensionsofDiv]);

  function renderContent() {
    return (
      <div>
        width of div: {dimensionsofDiv.width}
        <br />
        height of div: {dimensionsofDiv.height}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {dimensionsofDiv && renderContent()}
      dimensions of image width{dimensionofImg && dimensionofImg.width}, height
      {dimensionofImg && dimensionofImg.height}
      <div
        style={{ height: 500, width: 300, border: "solid 1px red" }}
        ref={myRef}
      >
        <img
          style={{
            maxWidth: `${imagedimensions && imagedimensions.maxWidth}`,
            maxHeight: `${imagedimensions && imagedimensions.maxHeight}`,
            width: `${imagedimensions && imagedimensions.width}`,
            height: `${imagedimensions && imagedimensions.height}`
          }}
          onLoad={(e) => {
            setDimensionofImg({
              width: e.currentTarget.offsetWidth,
              height: e.currentTarget.offsetHeight
            });
          }}
          alt=""
          src={props.src}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Example from "./component"
const src = "https://picsum.photos/100/800/?random";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Example src={src}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the width to your `div` width and leave the `height` as auto to maintain `ratio`.

```css
.container { width: 500px }

.container img { max-width: 100%; height : auto }
```

Comment: I am looking for something like, when you get the image, you calculate the image height and width accordingly to the size of div. Then you set the height and width of image dynamically

Answer (score 0):

The most closest thing to what you need is `object-fit: contain` property.
This will fill the div depending whether it is landscape (will take all the width) or portrait (will take all of the height), and all this maintaining the aspect ratio. You just need to provide dimensions for `div`.

```
div {
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
}

img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: ok, I have tried some logic, please refer the link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-firefly-yc636?file=/src/component.js